# List videos from an album via Facebook GraphAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the album content list but Facebook GraphAPI doesn't returns the videos in an album.

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/ALBUM_ID/?fields=video_count&access_token=TOKEN"
```

Returns:

```
{
  "video_count": 1,
  "id": "1234567890"
}
```

But I can't request the video or every content list beside photos. How could I get the album content list with all videos and photos?